# Раскрывающиеся строки таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица, в которой при нажатии на строку показывается строка с доп.информацией, при повторном нажатии скрывается.

```
$('tr').click(function() {$(this).next().toggle()});
```

При одной таблице на странице работает.
Добавил вторую таблицу и работает только на второй таблице.
Понятно, что надо указать id таблицы, но никак не пойму как это сделать.

```
<div id="week_table"></div>
```

После идет выполнение JS

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax/ajax_arfs.php",
  data: "op=week_list",
  success: function(msg) {
    $("#week_table").html(msg);
   }
});
```

Строится 2 таблицы, т.е. в msg возвращается

```
<table id="current">
.............
</table>
<table id="week">
.............
</table>
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: вообще вы добавляете обработчик для всех строк, не важно в какой таблице они находятся, важно чтобы на момент выполнения этой строчки они уже были добавлены в DOM

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, работает.

Comment: пожалуйста конечно :-D но я не понял чем именно помог :-) если у вас была проблема и вы ее решили, вы можете добавить свой собственный ответ с описанием решения

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: еще одно пояснение, вы вставляете две таблицы в один див?

Comment: Да, в один див.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае подойдет делегирование событий с помощью функции [*on*](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Суть этой функции заключается в том, что событие вешается на уже существующий элемент, обычно контейнер в котором лежат нужные элемента, и вторым параметром указывает от каких именно элементов обрабатывать событие.

Предположим, что

```
<div id="week_table"></div>
```

есть в разметке всегда, тогда его можно использовать в качестве контейнера на которое будем навешивать основное событие.

```
// вместо tr можно использовать более специфичный селектор, 
// например с указанием большей вложенности и/или классов, 
// но в данном случае хватит просто tr
$('#week_table').on('click', "tr",function(){ 
    $(this).next().toggle(); // this внутри функции будет указывать на tr по которому кликнули.
});
```

Данный код может располагаться либо в блоке `ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

Либо в теге скрипт, который объявлен после нужного дива.

Так же важно - данный код

```
$(this).next().toggle();
```

будет скрывать любую следующую строку, то есть, если в таблице три строки, то при клике на первую будет скрываться/показываться вторая, а при клике на вторую будет скрываться/показываться третья. Возможно стоит как-то отметить классом конкретную строку которую надо скрывать, но это не относится к сути вопроса о событиях.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, все работает отлично.
Только еще вот вопрос. При клике показывается строка и если на нее кликнуть, то исчезает следующая строка, а она должна остаться. Т.е. можно ли как-то сделать чтобы при клике на появившуюся строку не было никаких действий?

Comment: @thecoder, об этом как раз последние абзацы, так как событие навешивается на все строки - то и работать будет со всеми. Проще всего в разметке которая возвращается с сервере пометить строки при клике на которые должно что-то случаться классом, например _clickable_, и немного изменить скрипт `$('#week_table').on('click', "tr.clickable",function(){ `

Answer (score 0):

@Grundy написал важную вещь, что

> важно чтобы на момент выполнения этой строчки они уже были добавлены в DOM

Т.е. код $('tr').click(function() {$(this).next().toggle()}); для корректной работы должен выполнятся после того как на странице будут выведены все таблицы, в моем случаем этот код выполнялся после вывода одной таблицы, соответственно работало только на одной таблице.

Comment: можете поместить этот код в событие `ready`: `$(document).ready(function(){$('tr').click(function() {$(this).next().toggle()});})` Тогда он выполнится когда DOM уже будет построен и все будет работать, если конечно таблицы не строятся динамически, например, по результатам ajax запроса

Comment: В том то и дело, что они строятся по ajax запросу

Comment: тогда покажите пример разметки, в вашем вопросе и как вы используете ajax, я могу подсказать как в вашем случае использовать делегирование событий jquery :-)

Comment: в вопрос, в комментариях код очень плохо выглядит:)